# Line integral along the curve $\gamma(t)=(4 \cos t, 4 \sin^2 t) $

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

Let us consider the vector field in the plane:
$$\vec{F}=\left(x \frac{e^{x^2+y^2} - e}{x^2+y^2},y\frac{e^{x^2+y^2} - e}{x^2+y^2}\right)$$
calculate the line integral along the curve defined by:
$$\gamma:
\begin{cases}
x=4 \cos t \\
y=4 \sin^2 t\\
\end{cases}
$$
with $t\in[0,\pi/2]$.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Is $y=4\sin^2t$ or $y=4\sin t$? If $y=4\sin t$, then we would have $x^2+y^2=4^2$.

Comment: @Paul The result is the same in any case.

Comment: @Mark the vector field is conservative.

Comment: this line integral is funnily zero!

Comment: @Mehdi, why it is zero?

Comment: @Paul, it is $y=4\sin^2 t$.

Comment: The vector field is conservative. But F isn't defined when x and y get simultaneously zero; is it valid anymore to claim that the integral is independent of path?

Comment: @AhmedHussein It's enough that $\vec F$ is conservative in a connected set containing the path, this can be done 'away' from the origin, so it works out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Git Gud remarked, the integral is independent of path (because the vector field F is conservative). So choose the path along (4cos(t), 4sin(t)) instead. The answer is eventually 0.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a direct evaluation using this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral)

$\begin{align}
dx&=-4\sin t \\
dy&=8\cos t \sin t \\
F&=\Big(\frac{2[\exp{(2\cos 4t +14)}-e] \cos t }{7+\cos 4t},\frac{2[\exp{(2\cos 4t +14})-e] \sin^2 t }{7+\cos 4t}\Big)
\end{align}$

Your integral will hence be

$\begin{align}I&=-\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{2[\exp{(2\cos 4t +14})-e] \sin 4t }{7+\cos 4t}dt\\
&=-\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{2[\exp{(2\cos 4t +14})-e] \sin 4t }{7+\cos 4t}dt-\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{2[\exp{(2\cos 4t +14})-e] \sin 4t }{7+\cos 4t}dt\\
&=-\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{2[\exp{(2\cos 4t +14})-e] \sin 4t }{7+\cos 4t}dt+\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{2[\exp{(2\cos 4t +14})-e] \sin 4t }{7+\cos 4t}dt\\
&=0.
\end{align}$

where at last I have changed the variable for the second integral from $t$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}-t$.

Answer (score 0):

At first compute $\vec F(t)$ by substituting the expressions $x,y$ given by your curve $\gamma$. Then compute the differentials $dx,dy$ for $x,y \in \gamma$ in dependence on $t$. Finally, evaluate the scalar product $(dx,dy)\vec F$ and calculate the integral over the interval of $t$.